# Whats wrong with this CSS Code: height: calc(2748px / 100vw * 349px);?

Tags: css, wordpress, image, calc

I want to create a header with a background image. Now, the size of the image is 2748px wide and 349px high. And the image should always fit in. So I created this CSS code, but something is wrong.

```
height: calc(2748px / 100vw * 349px);
```

Comment: how do you know that something is wrong?

Comment: you cannot divide with a unit nor mulltipy two different units

Comment: use `width:100%; aspect-ratio:2748/349;` or something like that

Comment: @jsotola I know it because it says "invalid property value"

Comment: @LucaMelop why did you not share that information?